# Deriving equation of motion from finite sum potential

Tags: calculus, summation, wave-equation

I have a one-dimensional chain of identical atoms with mass *m*. There are "springs" between all pairs of atoms. Thus, the elastic energy is

$$
U = \frac{1}{2}\sum_j\sum_{l > 0} K_l (u_j - u_{j+l})^2,
$$

where $K_j$ is spring constant and $u_j$ is the displacement of $j$-th atom. I need to find the equation of motion

$$
m\ddot{u}_j = -\frac{\partial U}{\partial u_j}.
$$

So far I managed to get the following equation

$$
 m\ddot{u}_j = \sum_{n = 1}^{j - 1} K_n(u_n - u_j) -K_j \sum_{l>0} (u_j - u_{j + l}),
$$
but this does not seem right because later I need to find a dispersion relation and it looks like it will depend on $j$.

Edit:
To simplify thing, let's assume periodic boundary conditions $u_{N +1} = u_1$

Comment: Are you certain about your expression for $-\partial_j U$? I find: $-\partial_j U=\sum_l K_l (u_{j-l}-2u_j+u_{j+l})$

Comment: @Sal Well, That is the thing, I was not sure if I had the right $-\partial_j U$. But I finally figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

So, as @Sal mentioned, the right solution is

$$
m\ddot{u}_j = \sum_{l > 0}K_l(u_{j-l} - 2u_{j} + u_{j+l})
$$